# Trouble with getting VBScript to list programs installed under 32 bit folder

Tags: vbscript

I have a script that will take all of the programs in the "program files" folder under the C drive and list them out in a text file. I need it to also be able to put the programs installed under the "program files (x86)" folder as well. I Scrapped this code together from a couple different sources, so I'm having a little bit of difficulty with it.

Here is the code:

```
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
Dim strComputer, strKeyPath
Dim objReg, strSubkey, arrSubkeys
Dim Name, Version

'Gets ready for the part where it makes the text file
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strDirectory = "InstalledPrograms.txt"
strDirectory = objFSO.BuildPath(WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop"), strDirectory)

Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
outFile= strDirectory
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outFile, True)

strComputer = "."

'Registry key path of Control panel items for installed programs
strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\"

Set objReg=GetObject( _
    "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
    strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

objReg.EnumKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, arrSubkeys

'Enumerate registry keys.
For Each strSubkey In arrSubkeys
    objReg.GetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath & strSubkey, "DisplayName", Name
    If Name <> "" Then
        objReg.GetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath & strSubkey, "DisplayVersion", Version
        objFile.Write vbCrLf & Name & " | " & Version
        objFile.Write "  "
    End If
Next

WScript.Echo "Installed Programs listed successfully in the InstalledPrograms.txt file on your desktop."
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: And what might that "bit difficulty" be exactly?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers maybe it’s the fact they never check the 32-bit registry anywhere in that code if run on a 64-bit OS.